# How to a assign data from one object another object of a different type that inherits from the original object?

Tags: c#

I have Two Classes:

```
class object {
    int id{ get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    string description { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class extendedObject : object {
        int quantity { get; set; }
        string moreDetail{ get; set; }
    }
```

I want to assign the properties of object to the extended object.

for example extendedObject = (extendedObject)object;

Comment: the name of the class is `object`?

Comment: These are just example names to make it clear

Comment: It's actually better to use another name, since object is a keyword in C#, that's why it's not exactly clearer :) You can use for example `BaseClass`, `InheritedClass` or something similar

Comment: You can't cast from a base class to a derived class (unless the object actually *is* an instance of that derived class). I would suggest using something like Automapper to copy the properties across.

Comment: Don't confuse the reference to an object with the object it's self. extendedObject = (extendedObject)object; is only working with references, not copying data. You could, for example, create a constructor for the extended object which takes an object as it's parameter, and copies the fields out of the base object into the versions in the extended object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By language design, you can't cast a `BaseObject` to `ExtendedObject`.

You can't even define and `implicit` or `explicit` `operator` between them.

This is a possible workaround:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseObject baseObject = new BaseObject()
        {
           ID = 0,
           Name = "TEST",
           Description = "TEST"
        };
        ExtendedObject extendedObject = new ExtendedObject(baseObject);
    }
}

public class BaseObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedObject : BaseObject
{
    public ExtendedObject(BaseObject baseObject)
    {
        this.ID = baseObject.ID;
        this.Name = baseObject.Name;
        this.Description = baseObject.Description;
    }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string MoreDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example it looks like you are trying to assign a variable, not properties. That is not possible since inherited class cannot contain a variable of base class.

If you want to have a separate object of type extendedObject and copy data from object, then I am afraid you'll have to write the code yourself. Either use a copy constructor or a separate method.

E.g.

```
class extendedObject : object 
{
        int quantity { get; set; }
        string moreDetail{ get; set; }

     public extendedObject(object myObject)
     {
         id = myObject.id.
         /// etc.
     }

}
```

P.S. There are all kinds of mappers (special libraries) around like e.g. `AutoMapper`, etc. that can make this task easier for you, but I would not recommend that, it's just more expensive in the long run in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The direct cast not is posible. Your must declare the class as derived class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BaseClass c = new ExtendedClass() { id= 2, name = "Jhon"};

        ExtendedClass extended = c as ExtendedClass;        
        Console.WriteLine(extended.name);
    }
}

public class BaseClass 
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedClass : BaseClass 
{
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string moreDetail{ get; set; }
}
```